# Connecting to a MySQL database through SSH PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

For my University project I am connecting to a MySQL database. As of covid 19 I can't go to uni so have to do it remotely can anyone help with the PHP connection?

SSH Hostname: ssh.University.uk:2223
SSH Username: s4905304
SHH Password: ....
SSH Key File:blank

MySQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1
MySQL Server Port:3306
Username:s4905304
Password:.....

Comment: I think your university would be the best placed to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Step 1.**

Set up an `SSH tunnel` to your `MySQL` database server (preferably, through a `Jumpbox` for security).

```
ssh -fNg -L 3307:10.3.1.55:3306 username@ssh_jumpbox.com
```

*The key here is -L which says we're doing local port forwarding.*

**Local Port Forwarding Syntax**

```
<local_workstation_port>:<database_server_addr_remote_end_of_tunnel>:<database_server_port_remote_end>
username@ssh_proxy_host.com
```

Other switches are:

- -f (go to background)
- -N (do not execute a remote command)
- -g (allow remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports)

Private Key Authentication, add (-i) switch to above:

`-i /path/to/private-key`

**Step 2.**

Tell your local `MySQL` client to connect through your `SSH tunnel` via the local port `3307` on your machine (`-h 127.0.0.1`) which now forwards all traffic sent to it through the `SSH tunnel` you established in step 1.

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u dbuser -p passphrase`

Data exchange between client and server is now sent over the encrypted SSH connection and is secure.

Tunneling directly to your database server is not recommended - having a database server directly accessible from the internet is a huge security liability. Make the tunnel target address the internet address of your Jumpbox/Bastion Host (see example in step 1) and your database target the *internal* IP address of your database server on the remote network. SSH will do the rest.

Credit to Chris Snyder's great article at http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html

**Step 3.**

> **Connecting. DSN**
>
> `PDO` has a fancy connection method called DSN. It's nothing
>   complicated though - instead of one plain and simple list of options,
>   `PDO` asks you to input different configuration directives in three
>   different places:
>
> - `database driver`, `host`, `db (schema) name` and `charset`, as well as less frequently used `port` and `unix_socket` go into DSN;
> - `username` and `password` go to constructor;
> - all other options go into options array.
>
> where `DSN` is a semicolon-delimited string, consists of `param=value`
>   pairs, that begins from the driver name and a colon:
>
> ```
>        mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;port=3306;charset=utf8mb4
> driver^    ^ colon         ^param=value pair    ^semicolon
> ```
>
> Note that it's important to follow the proper format - no spaces or
>   quotes or other decorations have to be used in DSN, but only
>   parameters, values and delimiters, as shown in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php).
>
> Here goes an example for `MySQL`:
>
> ```
>  $host = '127.0.0.1';
> $db   = 'test';
> $user = 'root';
> $pass = '';
> $charset = 'utf8mb4';
>
> $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
> $options = [
>     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
>     PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
>     PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
> ];
> try {
>      $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
> } catch (\PDOException $e) {
>      throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
> }
> ```

Quoted from: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn

Comment: See my edit. I have put the quoted contents in the quote block. This way people know which words are yours and which ones are quoted. In future if you ever copy and paste text, which was not written by you, please use quote block.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant, the block quotes not being used. Ha, ya, I agree it helps but it was clear before to anyone interested to actually read and not just skim. Still, good practice to use the blockquotes, I'll keep that in mind. PS: you're a stickler, anyone tell you that? It can be a bad thing some of the time ^_^. thanks for editing and the help.